# Cannot use variable declared with Ruta DECLARE

Tags: java, uima, ruta

I am trying to write some Ruta Rules for capturing 'is-a' relations between things. I have a Relation class that includes a entity1 and entity2 attributes, which point to the two things involved in the relation.

My understanding is that I have to "capture" those two elements with annotations that are DECLARED, so that I can later on set them as attributes of the Relation annotation.

So my rule has this:

```
 DECLARE Token Thing1;
 DECLARE Token Thing2;
```

But somehow, when I try to mark a token as being Thing1 or Thing2, Ruta tells me that it can't access that type.

Here is a test that illustrates the problem

```
@Test
public void test__Ruta__BUG__DeclareNotWorking() throws UIMAException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
    final class RulesRunner {
        public void applyRules(JCas cas, String[] rules) throws AnalysisEngineProcessException, InvalidXMLException, ResourceInitializationException, ResourceConfigurationException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
            for (String aRule: rules) {
                Ruta.apply(cas.getCas(), aRule);
            }
        }
    }

    RulesRunner runner = new RulesRunner();

    JCas cas = JCasFactory.createJCas();
    cas.setDocumentText("A cat is a kind of mammal.");

    // Tokenize the string
    String[] rules = new String[] {
            "ANY{REGEXP(\"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\") -> Token};",
            "ANY{REGEXP(\"[^ a-zA-Z0-9]+\") -> Token};"
    };
    runner.applyRules(cas, rules);

    // Capture the "is-a" relation between 'cat' and 'mammal' and 'car' and 'vehicle'
    rules = new String[] {
        "DECLARE Token Thing1; \n" +
           "DECLARE Token Thing2; \n" +
           // This results in: 'not able to resolve type: Thing1'
           "Token{ -> MARK(Thing1)} " +
           "Token{REGEXP(\"is\") -> RutaNevermind}  " +
           "Token{REGEXP(\"a\") -> RutaNevermind}  " +
           "Token{REGEXP(\"kind\") -> RutaNevermind}  " +
           "Token{REGEXP(\"of\") -> RutaNevermind}  " +
           "Token{ -> MARK(Relation, 1, 6)}  " +
           ";" 
    };
    runner.applyRules(cas, rules);

    for (Relation aRelation: JCasUtil.select(cas, Relation.class)) {
        System.out.println("Got Relation="+aRelation.getCoveredText());
    }
}
```

Note that I also tried with the following declarations instead:

```
DECLARE Thing1;
DECLARE Thing2;
```

and

```
DECLARE Thing1 Token;
DECLARE Thing2 Token;
```

and

```
DECLARE Token thing1; // Obviously, changed the MARK statement accordingly
DECLARE Token thing2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found a way to make empty actions work, but I did find a workaround. Basically, I have an annotation class RutaNull, and whenver I need to use an empty action, I will use MARK(RutaNull). But if anyone has an answer to how to make empty actions work, I would still love to hear it.

Comment: Actions are not required. You can simply omit them, but you also need to remove the `->` with indicates that there is an action.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to consider here:

DECLARE does not declare a variables but a UIMA type. A declaration of a variable for a type would look like: `TYPE myTypeVar;`. I assume that you did not mean a variable in your question but a type.

The type system of the CAS in UIMA is static after the CAS is created. The ruta rules cannot extend it by a DECLARE statement when the rules are executed, when the analysis engines processes the CAS. There is separate functionality in Ruta to create a type system description of a ruta script which contains type descriptions for each declaration. Normally, this is done on "compile" level, e.g., by the ruta-maven-plugin or the Ruta Workbench. If you need to use it programmatically like in the code of your question, you can either add the type manually or you use the RutaDescriptorFactory. Here's some [code](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/uima/ruta/trunk/ruta-core/src/test/java/org/apache/uima/ruta/descriptor/GenerateDescriptorTest.java) how it works. If you want to create the CAS using uimaFIT's factory, you can simply use the created TypeSystemDescription as an argument there.

Actions are not required at rule elements. You can simply omit them, but you also need to remove the arrow `->`. You can also write rule without a single action, e.g., for using it as a query statement in the Query View of the Ruta Workbench.

The DECLARE statement declares new types. You can provide an optional parent type for the new types, which is of course then the super type of the new type. If `Thing1` is your new type, then `DECLARE Thing1 Token;` is not valid. but `DECLARE Token Thing1;` is. `DECLARE Thing1;` sets the super type to `uima.tcas.Annotation`. I would not recommend using Token as a super type.

The definition of the type `Relation` is not given in the question. Does this Type already exist? If not, the same applies as for the other types: You need to include it in the type system of the CAS.

**Maybe the most important note:** you do not even need to declare a new type which maybe avoids your problem overall. There are several ways to fill the features of an annotation with other annotations. There are several examples in the [1.4 Learning by Example](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.overview.examples) part of the ruta documentation, e.g., CREATE, GATHER, implicit actions, variables, label expression. It mostly depends on the definition of your `Relation` and on the actual use case. In your example, the rules could look like (Relation is one of your types?, no escaped quotes):

```
//DECLARE Relation (Token source, Token target); just a comment how the Relation type is assumed to be defined
(t1:Token "is" "a" "kind" "of" t2:Token){-> Relation, Relation.source=t1, Relation.target=t2};
```

or...

```
Token "is" "a" "kind" "of" Token{-> GATHER(Relation,1,6,"source"=1,"target"=6)};
```

You should probably optimize this rule by using different matching conditions, FILTERTYPE or -PARTOF.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*